# Avoid direct access to images in a directory on server through htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to avoid the direct access to images in a directory. Please let me explain what i need exactly becouse its a little complicated ;)

I have a directory called "member", and in this directory are the member directorys like "thorsten" and in this directory are the images of the members. So my it looks like this:

```
    index.php // The index.php is in the same directory as the member directory ;)

    member/thorsten/Thorsten-fTeVtE-Preview-01.jpg
    member/thorsten/Thorsten-gZ4Cd3-01.jpg

    .htaccess // The .htaccess should be here too :)
```

As you can see the member thorsten has two images now, one has the Word "Preview" in it and one not. The thing that i need is that i would like to disallow the direct access through an url to the image to all images that has NOT the word "Preview" in the file name.

And another tricky part is that the user directorys like "thorsten" in this example can have any name, for instance there can be also:

```
    member/melanie/Melanie-fh3wxcg-Preview-01.jpg

    or

    member/conny/Conny-fh3wxcg-Preview-01.jpg
```

I hope you understand what exactly i mean, the member directory name should be variable ;)

Thanks :)

Comment: If your goal is to make the non-preview images available only through your app, then I'd recommend moving them to a different directory -- one that is outside DOCUMENT_ROOT. Then the web server can't ever serve them directly.

Comment: Hi :) Thats a great idea but i need it with this directory order becouse i want to prevent only the non "Preview" images from access through a link ;) Thanks :)

Comment: You don't have to put them all in the same directory...

Comment: I know, but in this case i need to do that ;) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this

**Method 1**
When you deny access, even you can't access it through a webpage.

*Step 1*: Prevent access to mysite.com/member/

Into folder member, create new .htaccess file and add the following lines:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

*Step 2*: Set up an alternative way to access the files for yourself

Into folder member create file get_image.php and add the following code:

```
if( !empty( $_GET['name'] ) )
{
    $img_name = preg_replace( '#[^-\w]#', '', $_GET['name'] );
    $img_file = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/member/{$img_name}";
    if( file_exists( $img_file ) )
    {
      header( 'Cache-Control: public' );
      header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
      header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$img_file}" );
      header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
      header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
      readfile( $song_file );
      exit;
    }
}
```

And now, you can use this URL to get the song file:
http://mysite.com/member/get_img.php?name=file-name

**Method 2** Prevent access selectively.

Use Regex in your htaccess

```
.*?Preview.*?\.jpg
```

Comment: .?\.jpg will match all image files
You can apply the conditions required for files without preview to all the images, then add another line to apply the condition for files with preview to images with "preview" in file name. This will overwrite the condition for images with "preview" in file name and keep the original condition for the files without preview as it is.

Comment: What is the RegEx for all jpg files that has NOT the word "Preview" in the file name?

Comment: With ".?\.jpg" this i select all jpg images, but i need to get all but without the ones with the word "Preview" in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (except my RegEx can be wrong)

```
<FilesMatch "^member\/(?!preview)([a-z0-9]+)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
</FilesMatch>
```

or you can also do this:

```
<Directory /your/www/root>
  <FilesMatch "^member/$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "^member/?preview?$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hi :) I will try this later thanks :) But i need to get access to the images still on my own website, is that possible with your configuration? I only want to avoid access to direct links, i want to prevent that other displays the images on their websites from my server ;) Thanks :)

Comment: I t would be also really nice if you could explain your code so that i know what it exatly does so that i understand it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Thorsten The 1st guy, "FilesMatch" blocks access to all files on the given path (as it says "Deny from All") except those which have "preview" in their name. The 2nd one does the same but it denies directory access to all dirs under "member", except for files having "preview" in their name (FilesMatch is set to "Allow from All")

Comment: Hi, i have tested both now. The first one does not work, probably becouse the RegEx is wrong? And from the second one i get an internal server error. I have entered my Document Root and i still get the error. Do you know what i am doing wrong, or what can be wrong? Thanks :)